# Merge arrays on Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel and I'm trying to merge or join to arrays in one array, which have a one-to-many relationship.
These are the models:

```
class GroupMenu extends Model
{
    public function optionmenu()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionMenu::class, 'groupmenu_id');
    }
}
```

```
class OptionMenu extends Model
{
    public function groupmenu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(GroupMenu::class, 'groupmenu_id');
    }
}
```

Also I have this function which returns the following arrangement.

```
  public function getOptionMenus()
{
    $optionmenu = OptionMenu::whereHas('tipousuario', function ($query) {
        $query->where('tipousuario_id', session()->get('tipousuario_id'))->orderBy('orden');
    })->get()->toArray();

    return $optionmenu;
}
```

The output is like that:

```
array:17 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "groupmenu_id" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "groupmenu_id" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "groupmenu_id" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "groupmenu_id" => 2
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "groupmenu_id" => 2
  ]
```

My problem is that I want to have an array where for each groupmenu has within it the array of the optionmenu, something like that:

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "optionmenu" => array:3[array of all the optionsmenu that belongs to the groupmenu]      

  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "optionmenu" => array:1[array of all the optionsmenu that belongs to the groupmenu]  
  ]
```

Comment: Use `OptionMenu::with('GroupMenu')` and then you where statement

Comment: What is `tipousuario` - another related model for which you have an id stored in session?

Comment: Yes! tipousuario is another related model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all GroupMenu records with related OptionMenu records without any constraint

```php
$data = GroupMenu::with('optionmenu')->get();
```

However if you want to constrain the related OptionMenu records for each GroupMenu parent record based on the id of `tipousuario` - which you get from session as shown in your question then you can try something like

```php
$data = GroupMenu::with([
  'optionmenu' => fn($query)  =>
    $query->whereHas('tipousuario', fn($q) =>
      $q->where('tipousuario_id', session()->get('tipousuario_id'))->orderBy('orden')
    )
  ])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Donkarnash that solved my question!

Comment: @CesarArroyo Glad I could help. You may pls mark the answer as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.